# How to Update Password

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to change a password. Can you look for this and tell what's wrong? Some times I get a Syntax error in the `UPDATE` statement or even it is working the password didn't change in database. Here's my code:

```
Dim sqlquery As String = "UPDATE tblLogin SET pword = ? WHERE pword = '" & txtnewpass.Text & "' "
Dim sqlcmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlquery, con)

sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pword", txtnewpass.Text)

con.Open()

sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

con.Close()
MessageBox.Show("Your password has been changed", "Change Password", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know VB and VB SQL Syntax by heart, but a Quick Look at your code shows that there are at least two mistakes.

```
"UPDATE tblLogin SET pword = ?
```

should be

```
"UPDATE tblLogin SET pword = @pword
```

The

```
WHERE pword = '" & txtnewpass.Text & "' "
```

should be

```
WHERE pword = '" & txtoldpass.Text & "' "
```

Or make it with @param as well. You are trying to change password which doesn't exists yet.

Besides that, passwords should be encrypted in the database, and you shouldn't match (where clause) just by password. What if 2 users have the same password? You will change both user's passwords;)

Comment: Well, I noticed the @pword parameter only later. I made an edit.